# neovim Gruvbox appears all white and grey, I can't spot the mistake

Tags: vim, neovim

I can’t get Gruvbox to work. I’m using neovim. And I would really appreciate if someone can locate the mistake.

I’ve installed gruvbox in `~/.config/nvim/bundle/` and this is my entire `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file. I tried to add True Color in two different ways.

```
execute pathogen#infect()                                                       

filetype plugin indent on                                                       

set tabstop=4   

set expandtab                                                                   

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>                                                   

set termguicolors     

let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1 

colorscheme gruvbox
```

And when I run `:colorscheme` from inside vim I see gruvbox listed there. But it looks awful, no highlighting, all grey text on white.

I don’t know where the mistake is.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct the appearance, remove the lines below that set termguicolors

```
    set termguicolors
```